# Solving Differential Equations to satisfy a condition

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have two differential equations

$$\frac{dX}{dt} = -\frac{d\cdot N(0)\cdot X}{m+X}$$

and

$$\frac{dY}{dt} = \frac{d\cdot N(0)\cdot X}{m+X}$$

with initial conditions $X(0) = X_0$ and $Y(0) = 0$.

Given that $d,m,N(0),X_0 > 0$, how can I prove that $X + Y = c$ for some constant $c$?

Comment: Hum, $\frac{dX}{dt}+\frac{dY}{dt}=0$, no ?

Comment: Correct but I think that I am meant to find a value for the constant c. Seems all too simple for that to be the solution to me.

Comment: Then ask the right question, fix the $dN$ notation and define $P$.

Comment: Sorry, I did write the question down wrong. N(0) can be treated as a constant too and P(0) was a typo, was meant to be Y(0). It has been corrected now.

Comment: $X+Y = X_0+Y_0.$